# C# Conditional Linq query to get value inside parenthesis

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string

"Orlando, Orlando International Airport(MCO), United States" 
I want to get the code only MCO 
also if string does not contains the code then return null

Looking for a linq query that can do it in one line

Comment: Don't use LINQ. Use simple string methods or a Regex.

Comment: Are you certain that it must be LINQ? Regex is a much better tool for this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. You want to get the code (between ()'s) from several strings, or do you want MCO from this particular string? If it's the last situation, RegEx would be your best shot.

Comment: @kendfrey ok, which one should have better performance and speed regex or linq ?

Comment: @Pbirkoff yes from several strings

Comment: The best performance could well be using Substring and IndexOf. I don't know for sure. And LINQ doesn't even apply to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer regular expressions. See my example:

```
string resultString = null;
try
{
    string part = "Orlando, Orlando International Airport(MCO), United States";
    resultString = Regex.Match(part, @"(?<=\().*(?=\))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline).Value;
}
catch (ArgumentException ex)
{
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

And for the documentation of the expression:

```
// (?<=\().*(?=\))
// 
// Options: case insensitive; ^ and $ match at line breaks
// 
// Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind) «(?<=\()»
//    Match the character “(” literally «\(»
// Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*»
//    Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
// Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=\))»
//    Match the character “)” literally «\)»
```

Comment: in the above regex what is "part"

Comment: Part will be your input string. resultString contains the requested value.  I have added the part string in the example.

Answer (score 1):

```
       var value = "Orlando, Orlando International Airport(MCO), United States";
       var result = from p in value.Split(',')
                    let flg = p.IndexOf("(MCO)") > -1
                    select flg ? p : null;
```